# SoapUI Groovy script to compare db values against Json response

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hi Guys i am new to API automation in SoapUI. i want to know if it is possible to compare data received from the JDBC step against the Json Response. Currently how i am doing is, defining the xpath for each tag and saving values in variables and comparing them. is there a way to automate this in a generic way without defining xpaths for each element in xmls

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you need to provide more details such sample responses that you are trying to compare.

Comment: Let's say we have have a sql query in the JDBC step and got a response like, <Results>
    <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
        <Row rowNumber="1">
            <BANKTRANSACTIONID>23</BANKTRANSACTIONID>
            <VENUEID>4</VENUEID>
            <VENUENAME>Allnut Park</VENUENAME>
        </Row>
    </ResultSet>
</Results>
 and the the json response is like : {
   "data":    {
      "type": "banktransaction",
      "id": "23",
      "attributes":       {
         "cashAmountToBank": 43000,
         "chequeAmountToBank": 0,
                           }
               }
}

Comment: What do you want to verify or compare?

Comment: values came from the sql query should match with the values we received from the jason response. what i currently do is save the query values and jason response values in variables and then compare the values but what i want is.. a generic way without saving every tag value in a seperate variabale and compare.

Comment: values came from the sql query should match with the values we received from the jason response. what i currently do is save the query values and jason response values in variables and then compare the values but what i want is.. a generic way without saving every tag value in a seperate variabale and compare.

Comment: Can you check the [sample script](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/compare/JdbcAndJsonCompare.groovy) and make the changes as you needed? If you still have issue, please edit the question and add the details.

Comment: Marlon, have you got chance to look at the earlier comment and try something?

Comment: Yes but not working. what I actually want is to have a comparison between values received from the query and the values in the jason response. need to have a generic function kind of a thing which does the validation of each and every field values received from the sql query against the json response. how i currently doing is saving the values of fields in variables and compare the values but we have hundreds of fields in an api so defining variables to save the values come from sql query and jason response is not practical. so need a search kind of a thing which compare the values

Comment: I do not know what you mean by _not working_. That what was an example. You need to change it as per your data. Would you mind editing your question with what you have tried based on that sample? Your data need not be exact, but you need to provide the same structure of the response. Then some one will be able to help you out. Please edit the question and provide details.